# How can I keep the gnome-terminal open after a program closes?

Tags: command-line, gnome-terminal, .desktop

I have the following shortcut which opens an SSH instance. How can I modify it so that when SSH closes, the terminal stays open?

```
[Desktop Entry]
Terminal=true
Type=Application
Name[en_US]=ssh
Icon=/logo_sprite.png
Exec=gnome-terminal --geometry=... --window-with-profile=... --title=... -e 'bash -c "ssh -t -i ~/dsa.key cle@12.210.9.17 sudo -s"'
```

Comment: how to do this programmatically? Instead of using the GUI.

Answer (score 19, accepted):

#### 1. First option: edit gnome-terminal settings

In `gnome-terminal`, go to preferences, the "Title and command" tab. Then click the drop-down list "When command finishes", choose "Keep terminal open".

[image]

#### 2. If you prefer not to have an effect on all terminals

You can add `bash`as a last command. In my test,

```
Exec=gnome-terminal -e 'bash -c "gedit; echo Monkey; bash"'
```

did the job. In your command, you probably need to do it like:

```
Exec=gnome-terminal --geometry=... --window-with-profile=... --title=... -e 'bash -c "ssh -t -i ~/dsa.key cle@12.210.9.17 sudo -s; bash"'
```

#### 3. Keep the terminal open until you hit Enter

Another option is to place `read line` at the end of your commands. In that case, the terminal will stay open until you hit <kbd>Enter</kbd>

From my test:

```
Exec=gnome-terminal -e 'bash -c "gedit; echo Monkey; read line"'
```

Or in your command probably:

```
Exec=gnome-terminal --geometry=... --window-with-profile=... --title=... -e 'bash -c "ssh -t -i ~/dsa.key cle@12.210.9.17 sudo -s; read line"'
```

#### Notes

- Note that this launcher will "steel" possible other windows from `gnome-terminal`'s own application launcher in the Unity Launcher, since this launcher calls `gnome-terminal`in its "main" command. Cleaner would be to add the command as a shortcut to the existing `gnome-terminal` launcher (or any other launcher you'd like).
- Since the command in the launcher already calls `gnome-terminal`, you do not need to set `Terminal=true`.

Comment: But this affects all terminals.

Comment: @A.B. It does, but is that a problem?

Comment: I would say yes.

Comment: @A.B. added another option.

Comment: Thank you for detailed answer. However, it still cannot run. Like this command string is successfully open a new terminal form console or from a bash script in already opened terminal. But, cannot open a new terminal from desktop shortcut. It still immediately closes. In fact in Ubuntu 14 works well.

Comment: @RostyslavMalenko That surprises me, but I'll try to test on 15.04

Comment: @RostyslavMalenko The strange thing is, it does work on my 15.04. An alternative would be to replace `bash` by `read line`, so the `Exec= line` would be:  `Exec=gnome-terminal --geometry=... --window-with-profile=... --title=... -e 'bash -c "ssh -t -i ~/dsa.key cle@12.210.9.17 sudo -s; read line"'` Then the terminal would only close after you hit Enter.

Comment: +1: Except the first option, you read my thoughts. **;-)**

Comment: @Helio Thanks! That is actually a compliment :)

Comment: Why not create a special profile with "not quit as command end" and call that profile with `gnome-terminal --profile=myprofilenoendcmd` ?

Comment: @solsTiCe That is actually a nice idea!

Comment: how to do this programmatically? Instead of using the GUI.

Comment: It seems that no-one is looking for the behaviour that I would call keeping the terminal open. Is it possible to keep the terminal open and interactive after the command. When I try the above it stays open but stuck. I can't enter new commands.

Answer (score 5):

You can do this by simply adding '$SHELL' variable at the end of your command. See below example in Exec=.... line.

```
[Desktop Entry]
Type=Application
Terminal=true
Name=MDS Control
Icon=utilities-terminal
Exec=gnome-terminal -e "bash -c 'Your command;$SHELL'"
Categories=Application;
Name[en_US]=MDS-Control
```

Answer (score 3):

I played around with this code for a few minutes. I think I found a solution. Here is my (a bit oversimplified when it comes to the details) code:

```
[Desktop Entry]
Terminal=true
Type=Application
Name[en_US]=ssh
Exec=gnome-terminal -e 'bash -c "ssh"' && gnome-terminal --geometry=... --window-with-profile=... --title=... -e 'bash'
```

Hope this helps!

I just added a line of code executing gnome-terminal with raw bash using the && command.

EDIT: I just realized someone already solved it!! Oops!

Comment: This helped me - basically just needed to rerun the same `gnome-terminal` command without the `-e` option. I tried like 15 different techniques before landing on this one.