# gnome-terminal: run command and stay open?

Tags: bash, gnome-terminal

If I just write:

```
gnome-terminal
```

Will open a new terminal (and keep it open).

But when I run with a command:

```
gnome-terminal -- ls -a
```

This opens a new terminal, runs the ls, but then closes the terminal.

Whats a clean way of keeping it open ?

Comment: See here? https://askubuntu.com/questions/630698/how-can-i-keep-the-gnome-terminal-open-after-a-program-closes

Comment: @codlord cant rely on settings unfortunately. except if i could set them from script

Comment: Continue reading a bit before deciding the answer is not useful for you. Anser by  Md. Zahangir Alam (not the accepted answer) leaves the window open with an available shell.

Comment: @vanadium some of the command/options they use in that answer are deprected like '-e'. I tried one or two of the suggestions but just failed :/ I do like the idea with trailing bash command (or im not alien to it) - but so far have not got it working :/ Also I also have a "sshpass -p pass ssh bla bla bla"  that fails - I need to see why its failing but cant