# My terminal tabs running scripts are being automatically closed

Tags: scripts, gnome-terminal

I have some scripts running in my server, sometimes my scripts may crash, ok that is something normal, but since a few days ago I started to see something very weird, in my terminal, I have many tabs running different scripts, and suddenly one tab is closed and therefore the script dies, I have no idea why the tab is automatically closed I've never seen such thing, I would like to know some suggestions about what I could do to investigate this kind of problem.

I am using Ubuntu 22.04

Comment: What do your logs say about it?

Comment: I am not sure where I could find logs for the terminal tabs

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[This answer](https://askubuntu.com/a/630779/610789) to a similar question offers three methods to keep gnome-terminal open after your scripts exit.

Comment: Thanks, looks like it may solve my problem, it is hard for me to test because it is not every time that happens, but I will give this a try.